# What exactly are "launch tables" and "dog bones" in the context of SpaceX's Super heavy-lift launch vehicle, as shown in these images?

Tags: spacex, identify-this-object, launch-site, spacex-super-heavy

@geoffc's Pod Bay [comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58199202#58199202) and [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58199203#58199203)

> Great aerial photo of launch table with the 'dog bones' being installed. So curious how this will all play out!
>
> https://twitter.com/RGVaerialphotos/status/1399766481458565121

links to this [@RGVaerialphotos tweet with image](https://twitter.com/RGVaerialphotos/status/1399762876139769856):

> A total of 8 hold down or support clamps/arms for SH have been installed on the Orbital Launch Table.

and there are [more](https://twitter.com/RGVaerialphotos/status/1399766481458565121) including this one (right) with dog-bone-like structures.

[image: from @RGVaerialphotos tweet https://twitter.com/RGVaerialphotos/status/1399762876139769856] [image: from @RGVaerialphotos tweet https://twitter.com/RGVaerialphotos/status/1399766481458565121]

**Question:** What exactly are "launch tables" and "dog bones" in the context of SpaceX's Super heavy-lift launch vehicle, as shown in these images? Where do they go? What do they do?

Answer (score 1):

Launch table:
That thing on which the SuperHeavy booster will stand for launching. In turn, the launch table will be on top of the orbital launch mount, this thing:

[image: Image from RGV Aerial photography]
Image from RGV Aerial photography

Which together make this thing on the right under that SuperHeavy booster:
[image: Superheavy on launch mount, courtesy of Alamy]
Image courtesy of Alamy, if you want it without watermarks you know where to buy it.

From which the stacked Starship+SuperHeavy stack will launch.
Those nice tall legs give the exhaust somewhere to go, and will help to keep the dust down a *bit*. It also apparently voids the need for a flame trench, although Elon Musk has been heard to say "Aspiring to have no flame diverter in Boca, but this could turn out to be a mistake" Twitter 11:19 PM · Oct 7, 2020

The "DogBone" structures are the 20 clamps that support and hold down the stack before launch.

Comment: And yes, not having a flame trench turned out to be a mistake.